# Calling private method from a Public method in the same class

Tags: c++

I am trying to call the method gcd() in my multiplication method but I'm not sure what the correct way is. When I run the code below the console displays blank lines, when it should print a fraction. I've tried calling this->gcd(), fraction2.gcd() and gcd().

EDIT: Added cout override and main() to be able to run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fraction {
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Fraction fraction) {
        os << " " << fraction.numerator << "\n" << "---" << "\n" << " " << fraction.denominator;

        return os;
    }

    friend istream & operator>>(istream &, Fraction);

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
        int absNum1 = abs(num1);
        int absNum2 = abs(num2);

        while (absNum2 != 0) {
            int remainder = absNum1 % absNum2;
            absNum1 = absNum2;
            absNum2 = remainder;
        }

        return absNum2;
    };

public:
    Fraction(int n, int d) {
        this->denominator = d;
        this->numerator = n;
    }

    Fraction(int n) {
        this->numerator = n;
        this->denominator = 1;
    }

    Fraction() {
        this->numerator = 1;
        this->denominator = 1;
    }

    Fraction operator*(Fraction fraction2) const {
        Fraction multipliedFraction = Fraction();

        multipliedFraction.numerator = this->numerator * fraction2.denominator;
        multipliedFraction.denominator = this->denominator * fraction2.numerator;

        int fractionGCD = this->gcd(multipliedFraction.numerator, multipliedFraction.denominator);
        multipliedFraction.numerator = multipliedFraction.numerator / fractionGCD;
        multipliedFraction.denominator = multipliedFraction.denominator / fractionGCD;

        return multipliedFraction;
    }


};

int main() {
    Fraction fraction1 = Fraction(1, 2);
    Fraction fraction2 = Fraction(1, 2);

    fraction2 = fraction1 * fraction2;

    cout << fraction2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcd()` should work fine (`this->gcd()` should work too but would be unusual to see)

Comment: When I just write gcd() I get an error saying called object type int is not a function or function pointer

Comment: Since the function does not use the member variables of the class at all it would be better as a free function.

Comment: You already have a local variable called gcd - I missed that. That hides the function definition since its 'closer' to where you try to call gcd. `this->gcd()` will still work

Comment: I added some code so you can run it, when I try using this->gcd I'm getting an error reading "'this' argument to member function 'gcd' has type 'const Fraction', but function is not marked const"

Comment: so that code is nowhere near compiling. There is no Fraction constructor

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to add a big wall of code so I only added what I thought was neccesary. I forgot a few things, I added the whole file so it's able to compile

Comment: All of your operator overloads are declared wrong. `operator<<` and `operator*` need to take the `Fraction` by const reference, not by value. And `operator>>` needs to take the `Fraction` by non-const reference, not by value.

Comment: *"When I run the code below the console displays blank lines, when it should print a fraction."* -- this is good in that you have described your expected and actual results. However, how did you jump from this observation to blaming your `gcd()` function? That's quite a logical leap. (I'm not saying that logical leaps are wrong, only that they need to be explained. Don't leave your audience hanging.)

Comment: @sinafarheidar12 *"I didn't want to add a big wall of code so I only added what I thought was neccesary."* -- this is a good goal; it even has a reference page: [mre]. However, your code does not look minimal to me. It looks like your primary goal is still displaying the product of two fractions rather than demonstrating your issue. Reproduce the issue, not your goal functionality. For example, if the problem does not involve numerical accuracy, then don't worry about the numerical values produced; make `gcd()` something like `int gcd(int, int) { /* Stub function for testing */ return 8; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here goes

why `this->gcd` doesnt work. YOu have

```
class Fraction {
    int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
        int absNum1 = abs(num1);
        int absNum2 = abs(num2);

        while (num2 != 0) {
            int remainder = absNum1 % absNum2;
            absNum1 = absNum2;
            absNum2 = remainder;
        }

        return absNum2;
    };

public:
     Fraction &operator*(const Fraction &fraction2) const {
        ....
    }
```

in `operator*` `this` is `const` - it says so on the end of the statement. So you cannot invoke a non-const method on it.

`gcd` is a non const method.

This can be fixed by

```
 int gcd(int num1, int num2) const {
```

It compiles now

But as other have pointed out this does not need to be a member function. What does it even mean to say `frac.gcd(a,b)`, the method doesnt even look at frac.

You want

```
 static int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
```

now you can call it like this

```
int gcd = Fraction::gcd(multipliedFraction.numerator, multipliedFraction.denominator);
```

Note that I changed the calling signature of your operator* to be

```
 Fraction operator*(const Fraction &fraction2) const
```

this is what it should be as per

```
 https://gist.github.com/beached/38a4ae52fcadfab68cb6de05403fa393
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the time you took for this!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that gcd was not const which didn't allow me to use this->gcd and gcd function was returning 0 resulting in a divide by 0 error. Switching my gcd function to this worked

```
int gcd(int num1, int num2) const {
        int absNum1 = abs(num1);
        int absNum2 = abs(num2);

        while (absNum2 != 0) {
            int remainder = absNum1 % absNum2;
            absNum1 = absNum2;
            absNum2 = remainder;
        }

        return absNum1;
    };
```